# Is it possible to change a PPC Mac into an Intel-based Mac?

Tags: mac, powerpc

I have a PowerPC-based G5 and would like to develop for the iPhone/iPad. I understand that the latest version of the development tools require an Intel-based machine.

What do I need to change in my G5 to make it Intel-based? Is it only the processor? What else?

Comment: Buy a new one. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would have to change the entire logic board and all cards that have ROM chips.

Comment: +1 for putting "No" in a more positive way.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, you would need to replace the processor and and the logic board. Once you've replaced those parts, odds are you would need a new case, graphics card, and more... If you really want, look ar ifixit.com

(If you give a mouse a cookie...)

You are better off buying a new one. I bought a 21.5" iMac (Core 2 Duo) for iOS development. You can probably develop on the new Mac Mini, though.

If you *are* going to buy a new machine, wait for Apple's announcement this week. It may be significant.

Comment: Apple historically has been a "turn-key" solution.  Upgrade come in the form of entirely new system.  the G series was really the only series that encouraged upgrades. Though a good series that could attempt to keep up with the rat race, there is a generation gap now.

Answer (score 5):

You would have to buy a new Mac.

You need a new CPU, a mainboard to hold the CPU as the G5 Board won't do it. Then you need new Memory as G5 and Intel Macs use different memory. The Tower Case is incompatible, so you would need a new one. The Graphics Card will most likely need a different Firmware as well.

Short: There is no upgrade Path from a G5 to Intel.

Answer (score 0):

I may be downvoted for my answer, but you may make it cheap (I mean without buying a new mac, but buying something else). Take a look at osx86 project (google it and you'll get what you need).

Comment: Hackintoshes indeed work for iOS development, but sometimes Apple updates the iOS SDK and requires a new OS Version, which can be a pain to upgrade.